# comparing data fields to local time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am pulling date from local server:

```
$year = date("Y");
$day = date("d");
$month = date("m");
```

In my MySQL database, I have three fields, dateday datemonth and dateyear on a record.

Format of database values are 26,6,1971.

I want to select only records with dates that are equal to today or not past yet.

Second question, can I trick date() to give dates in eastern US time when the server is in the UK?

Thanks!!

Comment: For your second question, look at the class https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php as you can configure timezone properties against your date object to perform various calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You don't "trick `date()`", you use an API that is more useful.

```php
$year  = 1971;
$day   = 26;
$month = 6;

$src_tz = new DateTimezone("Europe/London");
$dst_tz = new DateTimezone("America/New_York");

$d = new DateTime('', $src_tz);
$d->setDate($year, $month, $day);
$d->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$d->setTimezone($dst_tz);

var_dump($d->format('c'));
```

Output:

```
string(25) "1971-06-25T19:00:00-04:00"
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

---

On a broader note you can simplify your life by storing and computing all dates in a single timezone, ideally UTC as it has no DST or other nonsense attached. Timezones then become solely the the domain of the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

To search for table rows that are equal to or greater than today, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE DATE(CONCAT(dateyear, '-', datemonth, '-', dateday)) >= CURDATE()
```

This is what it would look like if you concatenate PHP variables into a PHP string to create the query.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE DATE(CONCAT(".$dateyear.", '-', ".$datemonth.", '-', ".$dateday.")) >= CURDATE()";
```

For your second question, you can set the timezone in your PHP script with this command.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York')
```

Also, you can see more information about timezone here
[List of Supported Timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
[date_default_timezone_set information](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Final script

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$year = date("Y");
$day = date("d");
$month = date("m");

$query = "SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE DATE(CONCAT(".$dateyear.", '-', ".$datemonth.", '-', ".$dateday.")) >= CURDATE()";
```